# How to simplify Precision of number

Tags: javascript

How to convert a number (floating-point) with less precision?
I have a number: -3.442785098764216e+219
I need just 2 numbers after the decimal point.

```js
detailedNumber = -2.388912053427766e+202;
// works fine detailedNumber = -2.388912053427766;
simplifiedNumber = Number(detailedNumber.toFixed(3));
console.log("simple: "+simplifiedNumber);
```

Comment: That number contains no fractional digits - that's why `toFixed` won't work

Comment: how to convert -2.388912053427766e+202 into -> -2.388 ?

Comment: Do you care about rounding, or are you literally just trying to cut off any extra digits? (Also, are you trying to remove the `e+202`? That drastically changes the number)

Comment: Could you add to the question your expected output?

Comment: Are you aware of what the `e` notation means? You don't want to "simplify", you seemingly want to divide your number by 1000000000... (with 202 zeroes). What's the use case where that makes sense?

Comment: Perhaps OP wants `-2.39e+202`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very big number - it has 202 digits, and no fractional information. The least significant digit in that number still specifies multiples of `10^187` - hardly an "insignificant" value. Your best bet may be to use some string manipulation techniques:

```js
let simplifiedNum = (hiResNum, digits) => {
  
  // Depending on how big `hiResNum` is, `hiResNum.toString()`
  // will produce a value written with or without scientific
  // notation. This regex separates the scientific notation
  // from the significant digits.
  let [ , num, exp ] = hiResNum.toString().match(/^([+-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*)(e[+-]?[0-9]+)?$/);
  
  // Convert to float, and then back to string with a
  // truncated number of digits. Note the overall impact of
  // this transformation on the final result depends hugely
  // on whether `num` preceeded a scientific exponent!
  num = parseFloat(num, 10).toFixed(digits);
  if (num.includes('.')) {
    // Remove any trailing zeroes if `num` has a decimal
    while (num.slice(-1)[0] === '0') num = num.slice(0, -1);
    if (num.slice(-1)[0] === '.') num = num.slice(0, -1);
  }
  
  // Return the final result as a Number
  return Number(exp ? `${num}${exp}` : num);
  
};

let tests = [
  // Value in question
  -2.388912053427766e+202,
  
  // Powers of 10 from 10^10 -> 10^25 
  ...[ ...new Array(15) ].map((v, i) => Math.pow(10, 10 + i)),
  
  // Inverse powers of 10 from 10^0 -> 10^-15 (note precision can make these look like "0.000009999999")
  ...[ ...new Array(15) ].map((v, i) => Math.pow(10, -i))
];

for (let test of tests) console.log(`simplifiedNum(${test}, 2) === ${simplifiedNum(test, 2)}`);
```

The behaviour of `simplifiedNum` which I defined is sort of inconsistent. It treats numbers differently depending on whether they're big enough or small enough to be written in scientific notation. For this reason `simplifiedNum(0.001, 2) < simplifiedNum(0.00000001, 2)` - the latter is small enough to be shown in scientific notation, and therefore its value can be preserved, whereas `0.001` gets truncated entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You will lose A LOT of precision anyway. So for approximately value like this we can just convert it to string (this is just one of possible solution and not the best one I suppose):

```js
const detailedNumber = -2.388912053427766e202
const isExponentialNumber = detailedNumber.toString().includes('e')
const [base, exponential] = isExponentialNumber
  ? detailedNumber.toString().match(/(.*\..{0,3})(?:.*)(e.*)/).slice(-2)
  : [detailedNumber, '']
                                            
const roundedBase = parseFloat(base).toFixed(2)
const fullAproxNumber = roundedBase.concat(exponential)

console.log('detailed number:', detailedNumber)
console.log('rounded base:', roundedBase)
console.log('exponential:', exponential || '-')
console.log('full aprox. number:', fullAproxNumber)
console.log('lost precision: ', detailedNumber - fullAproxNumber )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use base 10 logarithms to figure out the exponent and then divide:

```js
let detailedNumber = -2.388912053427766e+202;
let exp = Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(detailedNumber)));
let simplifiedNumber = (detailedNumber / 10**exp).toFixed(2);
console.log("simple: "+simplifiedNumber);
```

I've omitted error checking for brevity and details may be wrong.

Said that, I'm pretty sure the overall idea makes little sense and you actually have bad data which you'd better fix at source.

It's also worth noting that, as per the latest updates, my answer does not comply with the expected algorithm, which appears to be:

1. Let JavaScript format the number as string.
2. If number size produces exponential notation, move the decimal point from the original position to produce a number in the ±0-9 range. Otherwise, round the original number.

This is a data corruption bug waiting to happen.

Comment: this was the result I was expecting but I does not work for -2433.7019999999998

Comment: It returns `-2.43`. How does it not work? What are the rules? Are there rules?

Comment: it should return  `-2433.70199` because I will write it to a DECIMAL(19,5) Mysql area with length 19 and 5 decimal points.

Comment: @CemKaan I'm updated my answer. You aren't placing decimal point randomly, but almost.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as a reminder for readers: The question has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: @CemKaan Oops... Sorry about that! I'd better remove from the answser.